# .*shrc and .*profile files after conda installation in mac

Tags: python, anaconda, zshrc, rc

After installing anaconda on my macbook I ended up with a bunch of files in my home folder. Some of these were there before but some of these have been created by conda.

```
.bash_profile - created by conda
.tcshrc - created by conda
.xonshrc - created by conda
.zprofile - was there before and conda did not add to it
.zshrc - created by oh-my-zsh and conda appended to it
```

Coming from linux, I only used to have a single thing - `.bash_rc`. What is the meaning of all these exra `rc` and `profile` files? Also, it seems like the lines that conda added to all these files was the same except for `.xonshrc`. Why is that?